# How to automatically fill input with content of div, both input and div displayed on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Input (placed in functions.php, but displayed on single product page)

```
function add_name_on_tshirt_field() {
echo '<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td class="label"><label for="color">Name On T-Shirt</label></td>
          <td class="value">
              <input type="text" name="name-on-tshirt" value="" readonly />                      
          </td>
      </tr>                               
      </tbody>
  </table>'; } add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_name_on_tshirt_field' );
```

Div = Breadcrumbs => also displayed on single product page. It stands for class .woocommerce-breadcrumbs or .woocommerce-breadcrumbs a.

My idea is using some kind of javascript code in the Theme Header (header.php), cause its displayed on every page of the website, so it should affect it.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add class to your input like:

```
<input type="text" class="input-to-fill" name="name-on-tshirt" value="" readonly />
```

And your JS (jQuery) will be like:

```
 $(".input-to-fill").val($(".woocommerce-breadcrumbs a").html());
```

Comment: Does not work. Where should I put this jQuery code? Tried to put in into header.php (wp-content/themes/mytheme) and single-product.php (wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates).

Comment: You should put after jQuery library, and better place for scripts is footer.php or something at bottom of page

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to add the script in your footer.php file of your theme under the wp_footer() function to be sure that if jQuery is outputted in the footer, your script will come after it. And don't forget the document ready to be sure that the script is executed only when the document ready.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

        $(".input-to-fill").val($(".woocommerce-breadcrumbs a").html());

    });
</script>
```